# How to make the Android In-App Purchase after some limit in the app

Tags: java, android, xml

I have developed an android app which is ready to be published in play store.

It has 3 modules what i want to do is make the first module in the app as a free version and the rest of the modules as Paid.

How can i do this can anyone tell me what i have to do for it

Comment: for your reference this will be helpful to you.,http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/implement-in-app-purchase-version-3

Comment: @abacus let us know what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

There Are Mainly three types of in app-purchase in android.
1.Managed
2.UnManaged
3.Subscription

If You want to implement this type of in-app in your application than you must be use Managed In app Purchase in your application.
[Reference.](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2014/09/02/android-app-purchased-demo-v3/)